# how do I remove a class if an element has a class that I'm looking for using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, removeclass

```
<a href='1.html' onclick='return false' class='selected'>video 1</a>
<a href='2.html' onclick='return false' class=''>video 2</a>
<a href='3.html' onclick='return false' class=''>video 3</a>
<a href='4.html' onclick='return false' class=''>video 4</a>
```

In the above code, I have 4 possible menus that appear depending on which link tag I click. Whenever I click on a link that is not selected and doesn't have the 'selected' class, I want to remove the 'selected' class from the previously selected video link tag, and add that class to the link that is being clicked on.

I have no problem adding the class to the link that is being clicked on, but how do I remove the class 'selected' from the currently selected link tag when I click on a different link?

I tried the following and it did not work

```
$('a').hasClass('selected').removeClass('selected');
```

but apparently it is not a proper function and gives me an error message in the error log in firefox.

Comment: does $('a.selected').removeClass('selected') work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass) returns a **boolean.** Just use the selector API appropriately:

```
$('a.selected').removeClass('selected');
```

That said, this is logically equivalent:

```
$('a').removeClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("a.selected").removeClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  // current link
  var $link = $(this);

  // find all siblings (fellow links) and remove selected class
  $link.siblings('a.selected').removeClass('selected');

  // make sure this class has the elected class
  $link.addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you write this as a two-liner? `$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected'); return false;`

Comment: @MattBall: For breaking it down purpose / clarity.

Comment: @MattBall Readability is far more valuable than creating a bunch of fancy one-liners.